# Bulk replace text in XML file with the filename

Tags: notepad++, xml

In an xml file, I need to batch replace over 200 files with appropriate tags, the xml template is:

```
<htf1>
    <title></title>
    <date></date>
    <quality></quality>
</htf1>
```

I have 200 copies of the xml file all named in the same system: YYYY-MM-DD_filename.xml, and need to input 'filename' into the title XML field, and ideally the 'YYYY-MM-DD' into the date XML field.

Is there a straightforward way to do either this, or just input the whole filename "YYY-MM-DD_filename" into the title field which would be a useable workaround as well.

Comment: I am guessing that you will need to write some code in some language able to process XML.  Hopefully someone will come along and prove me wrong.

Comment: This is possible but would require three steps as follows : (1) For all XML files, append the file name to the end as a new line using CMD, (2) Use the Notepad++ *Find in Files* to place the file-name into the `title` tag, (3) Use the Notepad++ *Find in Files* to delete the `YYYY-MM-DD_` part.

Comment: what OS?  For example, in Windows a batch script that iterates over all the files using a loop would be my approach

Comment: You've tagged with [tag:notepad++]. Does that mean you would consider answers only using this tool? For example, I can give you a UNIX/Linux shell script approach using `xmlstarlet`